# IIS URL Rewrite Rule Cached

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I've configured some URL rewrite rules in IIS which seems to be working fine. I did make a mistake in the one rule during initial setup, picked it up while testing in browser and fixed the rule.

The rule is now working fine in Chrome incognito, or any of the other browsers on my local machine, but the original Chrome continues to use the incorrect rule. I'm assuming it's cached. There's a couple of other users who are experiencing the same. They navigated to the site while the rule was incorrect and now they seem to have the same "cached" version of the original rule. Recycled application pools, even ended up doing an iisreset, but the problem remains.

Is there a way to force a client browser reload of the rewrite rules from the server? (I know I could potentially clear my cache on my local machine, but would prefer to "force" this from the server as I'm not sure how many other users are affected by this).

Comment: Modern browswers cache 301 redirections, so your only option is to clear browser side cache. Make sure during rule development you only issue 302 redirections.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks. My oversight then. Will keep it mind for future rules.

Comment: you could use iis client cache setting to clear the cache. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I followed the below steps.

1. Stop the "IIS Server"
2. Go to the "Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features" and Uninstall the "IIS URL Rewrite Module 2"
3. Install the "IIS URL Rewrite Module 2" again (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)
4. Start the "IIS Server"
5. Recycle the application pool
6. Restart the website

It's worked for me.

Comment: Browser side caches won't be cleared in this way. So, while you claimed it worked for you, technically that's impossible.